# How to allow apostrophe in text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I am using this regex to validate text:

```
    const regex = /^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']?$/

return text.length > 0 && !reg.test(text);
```

It allows text characters including special characters from different languages.
But I have problem to allow apostrophe "'" in this validation.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: put it at the start or end of the middle character class (or all three), escape it if your regexes are enclosed in double-quotes in your higher-level language

Comment: What is the problem? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: I use this regex for validation to prevent text like `alpha3`. `alpha` is valid. But I also want to allow `alpha'orelly`

Comment: And it [is matched](https://regex101.com/r/YkaEGq/1). Are you using Swift?

Comment: No it's JS I will update question

Comment: It is [still matched in JS regex flavor](https://regex101.com/r/YkaEGq/2). Please add the whole relevant code.

Comment: If use JS, use `\'` for escaping

Comment: I tried `/^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-'\' ]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']?$/` and still doesn't allow me to put `'` I am using react native if that is important

Comment: No need to escape `'` in a regex literal. Your code works if you remove `!` as it inverts the meaning of `reg.test(text)`. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeyrdQ?editors=1111

Comment: I don't get it. What could be reason that I am getting `false` from `reg.test("alph'onil")` it should be `true`

Comment: No idea, see https://jsfiddle.net/5r2qkm78/. Are you sure the quote is not curly?

Comment: Try `const reg = /^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z’‘' -]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘]?$/`

Comment: With the regex from the question, it does result in  "true" for `regex.test("alph'onil")`. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/x693wjnv/2/). So something else must be wrong in your case.

Comment: I see but seems that in react native it behaves different somehow :(

Comment: Solved it by adding `’` but I am not sure if this is best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input may contain curly single quotes, you need to add them to all those character classes that may need to match them:

```
const reg = /^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘’][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z’‘’' -]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘’]?$/
```

Note I also placed `-` at the end of the second character class so that it could always be parsed as a literal hyphen.

If your input string can have any hyphens not at start/end and the string length can be 1 char use

```
const reg = /^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘’](?:[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z’‘’' -]*[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'’‘’])?$/
```

That is, you have a regex with a `^a[a-]+a?$` like scheme, but I suggest `^a(?:[a-]*a)?$`, i.e. match `a` then an optional sequence of 0 or more `a`s and `-`s followed with `a` till the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding
ios use `‘’`
android use `'`
work in react native!